# How to add an "extendeddiscription" option to the \newglossaryentry command?

Tags: glossaries

By running the code below I get this result:
[image]
but I want something like the following image. In other words I need to be able to have an extra `extendeddiscription` option in the `\newglossaryentry` command so that I can add a "Extended description" to some of my entries. How can I do that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\glossarymark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
\glossarystyle{treegroup}
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
     }%
    {}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\noindent\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\par\nopagebreak}
  \renewcommand{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \hangindent0pt\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}%
{\dotfill}\ifx\relax##4\relax
    \else
      \space(##4)%
    \fi
    \space ##3\glspostdescription \space ##5\par}%
  \renewcommand{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
%    \hangindent##1\glstreeindent\relax
  \parindent##1\glstreeindent\relax
    \ifnum##1=1\relax
      \glssubentryitem{##2}%
    \fi
    \glstarget{##2}{##3}%
    \ifx\relax##5\relax
    \else
      \space(##5)%
    \fi
  {\dotfill}
##4\indent\glspostdescription\space##6\par}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\indexspace}
  \renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
}
\makeatother
\setlength{\glstreeindent}{20pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newglossaryentry{latinalph}
{
name={Alfabeto latino},
description={Latin Alphabet},
}

\newglossaryentry{exlatinalph}
{
name={Esteso alfabeto latino},
description={Extended Latin Alphabet},
parent={latinalph}
%extendeddescription={\lipsum[1]}
}

\newglossaryentry{set}
{
name={Impostato},
description={Set},
parent={latinalph}
}

\newglossaryentry{diamatrix}
{
name={Matrice diagonale},
description={Diagonal matrix},
%extendeddescription={\lipsum[2]}
}

\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{mylist}
\begin{document} 

In this chapter we introduce \gls{latinalph}, \gls{exlatinalph},\gls{set}, and \gls{diamatrix}.

\printglossary[title=Glossario]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using some deprecated commands, so I'm guessing you have an old version of `glossaries`. If you update to a newer version (at least 4.16), you can use `\glsaddstoragekey` to add a new key. For example:

```
\glsaddstoragekey{extendeddescription}{}{\extendeddesc}
```

This defines a new key `extendeddescription` that can now be used in `\newglossaryentry`. The second argument is the default value if the key isn't present. I've just left that blank. The third argument is the name of a new command that you can use to access this value (analogous to commands like `\glsentrytext`). For example, I've used `\extendedesc` here, so I would then be able to access the extended description for the `latinalph` entry using `\extendeddesc{latinalph}`.

I recommend you also switch off the expansion for this field in case you have any fragile commands:

```
\glssetnoexpandfield{extendeddescription}
```

I've updated your glossary style to use the newer style commands and added `\extendeddesc{##1}` to include the extended description:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\glsaddstoragekey{extendeddescription}{}{\extendeddesc}
\glssetnoexpandfield{extendeddescription}

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
 \setglossarystyle{treegroup}
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
     }%
    {}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \noindent\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\par\nopagebreak
  }
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent0pt\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
    {\dotfill}\ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
    \space \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription \space ##2\par
    \extendeddesc{##1}\par}%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
   \parindent##1\glstreeindent\relax
    \ifnum##1=1\relax
      \glssubentryitem{##2}%
    \fi
    \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}%
    \ifglshassymbol{##2}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##2})}{}%
    {\dotfill}
    \glossentrydesc{##2}\indent\glspostdescription\space##3\par
    \extendeddesc{##2}\par}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\indexspace}
  \renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
}
\setlength{\glstreeindent}{20pt}

\newglossaryentry{latinalph}
{
name={Alfabeto latino},
description={Latin Alphabet},
}

\newglossaryentry{exlatinalph}
{
name={Esteso alfabeto latino},
description={Extended Latin Alphabet},
parent={latinalph},
extendeddescription={\lipsum[1]}
}

\newglossaryentry{set}
{
name={Impostato},
description={Set},
parent={latinalph}
}

\newglossaryentry{diamatrix}
{
name={Matrice diagonale},
description={Diagonal matrix},
extendeddescription={\lipsum[2]}
}

\setglossarystyle{mylist}
\begin{document} 

In this chapter we introduce \gls{latinalph}, \gls{exlatinalph},\gls{set}, and \gls{diamatrix}.

\printglossary[title=Glossario]
\end{document}
```

The glossary now looks like:

[image: image of glossary including extended descriptions]